# Drawbacks of KSS

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Has anyone here used [KSS](http://kssproject.org)?

> ### KSS is an AJAX framework.
>
> KSS has both a client-side Javascript library and server-side support.
>
> The **client-side Javascript library** needs to be included in your page. It fetches Kinetic style sheets from the server, parses them and binds a set of action to browser events and/or page elements. It is clean Javascript code that can peacefully coexist with other clean Javascript librarys([sic](http://kssproject.org)) like JQuery or ExtJS. It is about 100k in production mode. You can integrate your own Javascript code by using its extension mechanism through plugins.

I'm currently working on a project that uses it. Are there any drawbacks and gotchas to be aware of?

What's its cross browser support like?

At first as was really put off by the fact that you don't write the JS by hand, and actually translates a CSS-like file to JS behavior, but seeing in action, I've got to say that it really works quite well. But I haven't done any cross browser tests yet.

Answer (score 1):

Some things that I've found:

- it sends HTML from the server, instead of XML and/or JSON and replacing them clientside, meaning higher messages (understandable)
- it has problems with scripts that add `iframe`s dynamically on a KSS widget that you reload
- some things are hard to debug, while others are made easy thanks to KSS' integration with Firebug

Comment: @Daniel: thanks. I'll try and keep this current with any problems I might find. I love it when a google search ends up here and the answers have exactly what I was looking for, I'm just trying to return the favor to the community :)